# solr administration

Tags: solr

Does anyone have any notes for an sysadmin supporting solr?  I'm looking for anything that might be useful for monitoring & metrics as well as troubleshooting.

Some useful links I have found are:
/solr/admin/stats.jsp and 
/solr/admin/analysis.jsp

In the logs I have noticed, other than the query, "hits", "status" and "QTime" values.  The documentation on what these mean is sparse at least based on the 100+ websites I have checked.  QTime appears to be the query time response in milliseconds.  Hits is some form of results but I'm not sure exactly what makes that up and I'm not sure about status.  Typically I see status come back as "0" but I have seen other numbers such as "5", so my thoughts that it could be either HTTP status codes or a 0 or 1 (good or bad) methodology isn't accurate.

All of the documentation I have come across is intended for developers.  Any sysadmin-centric documentation would be a big help.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/63803/solr-administration

Answer (score 1):

There's a great article on the Solr Wiki which explains how to use JMX to monitoring Solr:
[SolrJmx - Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJmx)